# Multiple dynamically added HTML Videos not muting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of html videos being added to the dom via jquery append (HTML string)

I want them to be inserted MUTED.

The problem is, right now they're not getting muted, even when I inject them with the muted prop.

When I remove the muted attrib on the video tag, and try something like `$('video').prop("muted",true);` it WILL mute them, but only AFTER they have all loaded.

Do I try adding the videos another way, or find an onLoad method for the html videos and trigger a mute function when they're ready.

jsfiddle of what they look like after append: http://jsfiddle.net/mvsMG/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `onloadeddata` HTML5 event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { //do NOT use $(window).load; it will not mute all videos
   // mute all the videos when data is loaded for each
   $('video').on('loadeddata', function(e) {
       //console.log('onloadeddata', e.target);
       $(this).prop('muted', true);
    }); 
});
```

Here is the **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/KX2g4/)**.

*Note: I don't know which browser you are testing with but you should check out this [**browser-support list**](http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/autoloop/) for HTML5 `muted` (`loop` and `autoplay`) attributes.*

Comment: It adds the prop, correctly but the videos do not mute... arg!

Comment: Which browser are you using? Also try toggling mute off and then on:   `$(this).prop('muted', false); $(this).prop('muted', true);`

Comment: chrome and safari, I think the parts that's missing from this equation is the fact the videos are being ADDED/REMOVED DYNAMICALLY. See here http://goo.gl/bFPTy

Comment: So I created an event that does the same thing on the video load as they get added, seems to be working. Thanks!